# How do I add dot-slash (./) as a sudo command rule in FreeIPA?

Tags: freeipa

I can't run scripts using dot-slash, because I don't know how to add it as a sudo command rule in FreeIPA. Users are not allowed to it.

```
./myscript.sh
```

[image]

How can add ./ as rule in FreeIPA like any other command rule:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add something like that to `sudo` in general, so I'm guessing it would be impossible to do so in FreeIPA as well. According to the sudoers man page

> A command name is a fully qualified file name which may include shell-style wildcards.

This means you can't use `./test.sh` because that is not a fully-qualified name.

As a side note, being able to enable this option would effectively mean that the user would be able to run anything they want with `sudo`, so you could as well remove any restrictions for them.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.